# Send message to Discord server based on input to text boxes?

Tags: c#, discord

I am trying to make an application app with C# in Visual Studio. I need some help with this, I want to submit a template like this:

```
<discord tag>
Link: <link>
Description: <desc>
```

Any help is useful! Thanks!

Comment: There's a [Discord.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.Net/) package on NuGet which will help with the API. Is that what you need help with specifically? It's not clear from your question. And I don't understand your template: what's the tag here, the #channel name or a user name, or something else? What's the link and description? Are you going to assemble the message body out of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to message a link to an article:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then try:

```
// implement your required logic for getting the tag
string tag = GetTag();

// implement your required logic for getting the reference
Article article = GetLinkWithDescription();

// Prepare the message
string message = string.Join(
   "\n", 
   $"<@{tag}>", 
   $"Link: {article.Link}", 
   $"Description: {article.Description}"
); 

// send the message
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
```